# How to typeset a radio button?

Tags: fonts

While it's easy to typeset a check-box (checked or not) in LaTeX (e.g., using `wasysym`), I did not find any way to typeset a radio button.  I could of course use TikZ, but is there a more "lightweight" way (i.e., using some font or combining existing characters)?  This is close:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{wasysym}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item[$\ocircle$] foo
\item[$\odot$] bar
\item[$\ocircle$] baz
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

but the dot inside `\odot` might be a bit too light.

Any suggestions?

Note: I am not interested at all in PDF forms; I want a printable document with a clear indication that one element of the list is selectable (i.e., a single-choice test).

Answer (score 15):

The selected and unselected radio buttons can be drawn via TikZ:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\radiobutton}{%
  \@ifstar{\@radiobutton0}{\@radiobutton1}%
}
\newcommand*{\@radiobutton}[1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\radius{height("X")/2}
    \draw[radius=\radius] circle;
    \ifcase#1 \fill[radius=.6*\radius] circle;\fi
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item[\radiobutton] foo
\item[\radiobutton*] bar
\item[\radiobutton] baz
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Some variation with shadow and ball:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\radiobutton}{%
  \@ifstar{\@radiobutton0}{\@radiobutton1}%
}
\newcommand*{\@radiobutton}[1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\radius{height("X")/2}
    \draw[radius=\radius,
      preaction={
        draw=gray,
        transform canvas={
          xshift=.7\pgflinewidth,
          yshift=-.7\pgflinewidth,
        },
      },  
      preaction={fill=white},
    ] circle;
    \ifcase#1
      \fill[
        radius=.6*\radius,
        shade,
        shading=ball,
        ball color=black,
      ] circle;
    \fi
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item[\radiobutton] foo
\item[\radiobutton*] bar
\item[\radiobutton] baz
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result with shadow and ball]

Answer (score 10):

May be this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{wasysym}
\newcommand{\radio}{\ooalign{\hidewidth$\bullet$\hidewidth\cr$\ocircle$}}


\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item[$\ocircle$] foo
\item[$\odot$] bar
\item[$\ocircle$] baz
\item[\radio] baz
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

You can use `\scalebox` and play with the size of `\bullet` if you want.

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Here I use a `\stackinset` to place a `\bullet` inside of a scaled `\circ`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\radiobutton}{\@ifstar{\radiobuttonON}{\radiobuttonOFF}}
\makeatother
\def\radiobuttonON{\raisebox{-1.5pt}{\stackinset{c}{}{c}{.35pt}{$\bullet$}{\scalebox{2}{$\circ$}}}}
\def\radiobuttonOFF{\raisebox{-1.5pt}{\scalebox{2}{$\circ$}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item[\radiobutton] foo
\item[\radiobutton*] bar
\item[\radiobutton] baz
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]