# How do you put a vertical line through the bullets in a list?

Tags: lists

I'm migrating a document from InDesign to Latex and can't seem to figure this part out. The title says it all. I've attached an image just in case.

I thought about making a table where each cell contained an itemize and then offset the bullet horizontally onto the border of the table but couldn't find anything on offsetting a bullet (not the text) horizontally.

[image: bulleted list]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your environment and roughly what you are trying to do. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Almost the same: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175831/list-environment-itemize-with-vertical-line-between-label-and-content

Comment: @Thruston I'm not sure what more can be added. I'm new to Latex and I don't even know where to start on getting that line to happen. That is close but I need the line to go through the bullets. Is there a horizontal offset setting? I couldn't find anything in that respect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

EDITED to provide `rbitemize` environment.  In this environment, `\item` will give a radio button with rules atop and below, with the optional argument of `\item` specifying the number of lines in the `\item` (if greater than 1).

I name the internal macro `\rb`, in reference to my code for a "radio button" at [How to typeset a radio button?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/236041/how-to-typeset-a-radio-button/236060#236060)

In the environment, `\item` is redefined to automatically call upon the internal `\rb` macro.  The `\rb` macro is basically a stack.  At the core (aka anchor) of the stack is a `\bullet` that is inset inside a scaled `\circ`.  That gives the radio button.  But stacked atop and under the radio button are rules.  The length rule atop the button is fixed, while the length of rule below the button is affected by the optional argument to the revised `\item`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand\rb[1]{\raisebox{-1.5pt}{%
  \stackunder[-2pt]{%
    \stackon[0pt]{%
      \stackinset{c}{}{c}{.35pt}{$\bullet$}{\scalebox{2}{$\circ$}}%
    }{%
      \smash{\rule{1pt}{2.1ex}}\kern.5pt}%
  }{%
    \smash{\rule[\dimexpr-#1\baselineskip+1.8ex\relax]{1pt}{%
      \dimexpr#1\baselineskip-1.8ex\relax}}\kern.5pt}%
  }%
}
\let\svitem\item
\def\rbsetup{\renewcommand\item[1][1]{\svitem[\rb{##1}]}}
\newenvironment{rbitemize}{\itemize\rbsetup}{\enditemize}
\begin{document}
\noindent Here is my itemize:
\begin{rbitemize}
\item foo
\item[2] bar continuing for an extra line to check if I can extend the 
  vertical bar downward, albeit manually
\item baz
\end{rbitemize}
Done with itemize
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Do you mind explaining how that macro works? Or directing me somewhere where I can figure out how you did this? Because right now I'm like "wow yeah this works, but I have no idea what's going on."

Comment: @thed0ctor I've added some explanation.  Does it help?  I would reommend reading the `stackengine` package documentation for more understanding of how I am using the stacking macros.  See http://ctan.org/pkg/stackengine

Comment: Yes that definitely helps get it started. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

A simple answer using only "standard" bits of LaTeX.  This is not very flexible, in particular it assumes your items are all single lines, but it might get you going on the road to something more robust.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\db{\mbox{\enspace\textbullet\hspace*{-2.8pt}\rule[-6pt]{0.4pt}{16pt}}}
\newenvironment{linked}{\begin{list}{}{%
  \renewcommand{\makelabel}{\db}
  \setlength{\itemsep}{-1pt}
  \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}
}}{\end{list}}
\begin{document}

However, a service-oriented paradigm is further compounded when taking into account
the evolution of specifications over a given time period.  
\begin{linked}
\item Small things in this list
\item Not very long or it will look awful.
\item OK?
\end{linked}
Conversely, any associated supporting element recognizes other systems' importance
and the necessity for possible bidirectional logical relationship approaches.  

\end{document}
```

[image]

[*The LaTeX Companion*](http://latex-project.org/guides/tlc2-ch0.pdf) is an indispensable reference for this type of customization.  In particular look at the section on "List Structures" in Chapter 3.

Comment: I've just started to read that book, and you're right: it's indispensable to make special things.